# How to change the image tag when i pubulish the docker image to harbor in visual studio 2022

Tags: publish, docker-image, custom-tag

i'm using Visual Studio 2022 for publishing the docker image to my docker depository (eg. Harbor), with the config "image tag: generate when publishing" (translated from chinese),
it works,but the tag name looks like  "20231124052959" ,UTC stirng, but i live in the UTC +8 time zone, how to solve this problem

### follow the gpt,but not works

To change the generated Docker image tag to UTC+8:00 (or any other desired time zone), you can modify the build process in Visual Studio 2022 by customizing the publish settings. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

Open your Visual Studio 2022 project.

Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Publish..."

In the Publish dialog, select the "Container Registry" tab.

Click on the "Advanced..." button.

In the Advanced Container Registry Settings, locate the "Image tag" option.

By default, the value for the image tag might be something like `$(BuildId)`. Instead of using the predefined variables, we'll replace it with a custom value.

Click on the ellipsis (...) button next to the "Image tag" field to open the Edit Token dialog.

In the Edit Token dialog, enter the following expression: `$(UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)`

This expression will generate the current timestamp in the format `yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss` using UTC time zone.

Now, we need to adjust the timestamp to UTC+8:00. To do that, we'll use a custom MSBuild property.

Close the Edit Token dialog and click on the "Edit" button next to the "Customize" field.

In the Customization dialog, switch to the "Build Events" tab.

In the "Pre-build event command line" field, enter the following command:

set `DockerImageTag=$(UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)`

This command sets the DockerImageTag MSBuild property to the current timestamp.

Click "OK" to close the Customization dialog.

Back in the Publish dialog, you should see the updated value for the "Image tag" field. It should now be `$(DockerImageTag)`.

Proceed with the publish process as usual.

By following these steps, you'll generate a Docker image tag with the current timestamp in UTC, and then adjust it to UTC+8:00 using a custom MSBuild property.